# drawAtPoint crashes iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, nsattributedstring

This simple drawAtPoint: withAttributes works fine on iIOS7 but crashes with a bad access on iOS8. I can't for the life of me figure out what is going on.

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:8];
UIColor *color = [UIColor blueColor];

CGContextSetTextDrawingMode (pdfContext, kCGTextFill);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(pdfContext, [color CGColor]);
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(pdfContext, YES);
CGContextSetShouldSmoothFonts(pdfContext, YES);

NSString *cardId = sharedCard.cardId;
[cardId drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(360, 602) withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:color}];
```

Comment: It appears that this only happens when I have an All Exceptions breakpoint enabled

Answer (score 0):

The exception is a C++ exception, which can be safely ignored.

Change the exception breakpoint from All Exceptions to All Objective-C Exceptions and that should take care of this issue.